# Categorize Data by Day of Week Python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, zip, enumerate

Given a list of lists in Python 2.7:

```
[['OCT 27, 2015',2,4,6,8],['NOV 03, 2015',1,5,9,2],['NOV 05, 2015',2,4,6,8]]
```

How do you print out the averages of the list in general; then averages based on the day of the week. EG:

```
2.5, 6.5, 10.5, 9, 1.5, 4.5, 7.5, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8
```

Where:

1.5, 4.5, 7.5, 5 are the average values produced above since Tuesday occurs twice in this list

2.5, 6.5, 10.5, 9 are the averages of the list in general

Then 2, 4, 6, 8 is the average of Thursday occurrences

I'm pretty sure I can use the zip() function to get all the like values. I'm just not sure about the averages calculated per day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,...)

How might I organize this into a clean looking tabular format with "Averages" and "Monday, Tuesday,.." as other headers

```
   Averages     Monday      Tuesday      Wednesday   Thursday   Friday  Saturday Sunday
2.5 6.5 10.5 9    0      1.5 4.5 7.5 5       0       2 4 6 8       0       0       0
```

Should I use an if statement?

Comment: Python has no switch statement.

Comment: Ugh I feel like a noob after that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like an excellent job for `pandas`:

```
from __future__ import print_function   
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

raw_data = [['OCT 27, 2015',2,4,6,8],['NOV 03, 2015',1,5,9,2],['NOV 05, 2015',2,4,6,8]]
pandas_data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=['Date', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
pandas_data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(pandas_data["Date"])
print(pandas_data)
print(pandas_data.mean())
```

output:

```
        Date  A  B  C  D
0 2015-10-27  2  4  6  8
1 2015-11-03  1  5  9  2
2 2015-11-05  2  4  6  8

A    1.666667
B    4.333333
C    7.000000
D    6.000000
```

This gives us our summary statistics for all columns, but for particular days of the week I'd do something like this (following the above code):

```
pandas_data["Day of the Week"] = pandas_data["Date"].dt.dayofweek
grouped_data = pandas_data.groupby('Day of the Week').aggregate(np.mean)
print(grouped_data)
```

output:

```
                   A    B    C  D
Day of the Week
1                1.5  4.5  7.5  5
3                2.0  4.0  6.0  8
```

`pandas`' convention for day of the week is Monday=0, Sunday=6

`pandas`' `groupby` function does what it says on the tin: It groups the data based on some criteria, in this case the column 'Day of the Week'. The `aggregate` function then runs the given functions on those groups and gives you the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` for it:

```
from itertools import groupby
import datetime


l = [['OCT 27, 2015', 2, 4, 6, 8],
     ['NOV 03, 2015', 1, 5, 9, 2],
     ['NOV 05, 2015', 2, 4, 6, 8]]


# Day of week as number. Monday == 0 ... Sunday == 6
def day_of_week(str_date):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, '%b %d, %Y').weekday()


stats = [None] * 7
for key, group in groupby(l, key=lambda x: day_of_week(x[0])):
    z = zip(*group)
    next(z)  # skip dates
    stats[key] = [sum(i) / len(i) for i in z]

print(stats)
```

output:

```
[None, [1.5, 4.5, 7.5, 5.0], None, [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0], None, None, None]
```